# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 355: invalid start byte

Tags: python, read.csv

I've been trying to iterate through a csv file with the following code:

`

```
import csv
import os, sys

directory = "/Users/aliharam/Desktop/Lamis File"
files = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    # checking if it is a file
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        files.append(f)
files.pop()

for i in files:
    with open(i, 'r') as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in datareader:
            print(row)
```

`

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aliharam/PycharmProjects/LamisTasks/Normalization.py", line 16, in <module>
    for row in datareader:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 355: invalid start byte
['\tAli Haram                                             \tAli Haram                                             ']

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I fix this?!!

I tried using

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(i, header= 0,
                          encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

and

```
with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fn:
  lines = fn.readlines()
```

both didn't work

Comment: This means this isn't a UTF8 file. There are a *lot* of duplicates, almost one every day. The best option is to tell whoever produced that file to save it in UTF8. The only other solution is to find what the correct encoding is and pass it as a parameter to `open` or `read_csv`. Try `latin1` and if you get garbled text, try using the encoding used in the country where the document came from. Unicode isn't some kind of escape sequence.

Comment: You can also use the `chardet` package to estimate the most likely encoding based on the contents of the file and the frequency of bytes/letters

Comment: The `Related Questions` column on the right of this page shows 10 identical questions. In all the cases, the answer is to find the correct encoding and use it in the `encoding` parameter of either `open` or `read_csv`

Answer (score -1):

The file your program reads contains character(at position 355) which does not belong to Unicode.

If we assume you are reading a Unicode encoded file, then there is an error in your data file. First you need to make sure the file your program reads is encoded in Unicode or not.

Comment: No, it's not an error in the file. Text files can be saved in several encodings, not just UTF8. Besides, the error already says this isn't a Unicode file. It's definitely not UTF8. Nor is it UTF16, otherwise the error would complain about `0x00` in the first bytes